# Can you use Popen and walk together in a loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, os.walk

I am trying to compress files in a directory and its sub-directories using an executable file compressor (7-Zip). I've set up a loop that automates the process, and the code does not produce any errors. However, it does not seem to compress anything. What I have written is:

```
import subprocess, os

path = 'directory-path'
newpath = 'new-directory-path'

for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7z.exe', 'a', '-mx1', 'blahblah', filename], cwd = newpath)
        p.wait()
```

It does output a file `blahblah.dat` in the `newpath` directory, but 1 KB file and should be a few GB. Of course when I hard-code in the file paths outside of a loop, it works just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're passing the filename to compress, but nothing about where to find that file. Also, can't you just [have 7zip handle the directory traversal itself](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/add.htm)?

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the reply! 7zip can do that from the command line. I'm just trying to write a script that can do the same thing. Doesn't the os.walk(path) put me in the dirpath location as it loops through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supplying the directory name of the file when you pass it to `7z.exe`, so it's looking for the file in the current directory. Use `os.path.join()` to combine the directory with the filename.

```
p = subprocess.call(['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\7-Zip\\7z.exe', 'a', '-mx1', 'blahblah', os.path.join(dirpath, filename)], cwd = newpath)
```